# What am I doing wrong with this for loop?

Tags: c, random, for-loop, sdl

I'm working on a piece of C code using SDL that's supposed to fill the screen with black and white pixels...It uses a for loop to fill the screen and a random number to decide whether each pixel is black or white.

It starts out working as it should for a second, but it slowly starts showing more and more white pixels until the screen is fully white and stays that way.  I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.  I have it print the number in num in the console and it continues to show random 1s and 0s like it should even while the screen is white, so I think the problem exists somewhere in the if else statement or for loop.

Here's the relevent code...

```
 /*outside main program loop*/
 17   int x, y, num;
 18   srand(time(0));

 /*inside main program loop*/
 28     for(y=0;y<=480;y++) { 
 29       for(x=0;x<=640;x++) {
 30         num = rand() % 2;
 31         if(num == 0) {
 32           pixelRGBA(screen, x, y, 255, 255, 255, 255);
 33         }
 34         else {
 35           pixelRGBA(screen, x, y, 0, 0, 0, 0);
 36         }
 37       }
 38     } 
 39     SDL_Flip(screen);
```

Comment: BTW: `srand(time(0));` is middle ages. Do not randomize if you do not need it for the visual effect.

Answer (score 5):

Two problems:

```
pixelRGBA(screen, x, y, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

RGBA means you have alpha, and you've set the alpha to transparent, so it won't render any black pixels. When alpha-blending, the pixel will be multiplied by the alpha, and the existing pixel multiplied by the inverse, and the two pixels added. So with an alpha of zero you get none of your new pixel and all of the existing pixel.

Also, your loops are <= rather than just <, so you're plotting too many pixels.

```
for(y=0;y<480;y++)
{ 
    for(x=0;x<640;x++)
    {
        num = rand() % 2;
        if(num == 0) {
            pixelRGBA(screen, x, y, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        } else {
            pixelRGBA(screen, x, y, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In one case you're making the color completely opaque and in the other completely transparent. While the RGB values should, indeed, be 0 in one case and 255 in the other, the Alpha should be the same for both cases, I think.